# Display categories and subcategories in customized Magento theme

Tags: magento, navigation, themes, customization, categories

I have a Magento script for a hotel booking platform. But there is no navigation with Display of categories included. So I tried to create one.
And so far after days I was successful: the nav-bar is shown and the categories of level0 also are shown, but that's already. The categorie links do not respond and subcategories do not appear by hover.

But if I insert`'$category->getChildren();` in top.phtml categorie links are working, but this generates also a

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function getChildren() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\stylish\template\catalog\navigation\top.phtml on line 63"

And here is the code with line 63:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
        <?php $category->getChildren(); ?>    (line 63)
    </ul>
</div>
```

What's wrong? Has somebody any idea to solve the problem? I'm relatively desperate and hope for help.

In a earlier version of the script I hired an freelancer (but I lost the contact) to fix the categorie navigation. It works on www.crazyrooms.de - and I tried to reconstruct his code changings on local xampp, but without success. By the way: I installed Magento 1.8 (instead of 1.7 before).
Thanks for any reply and your tips!

Comment: Are you checking in default magento or is there any customization or any third party theme?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a script from Apptha.com (Airhotels) and it works with another theme (stylish theme). So it's very complicated for me. I compared and checked the following files (from the freelancer and from the new version of Airhotels script) and changed them like the freelancer has done: header.phtml, airhotels.phtml, catalog.xml, top.phtml and navigation.php But nothing will help.

Comment: Here comes the hole code in top.phtml:                                                           <?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
  <?php
    /*
?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>   
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

Comment: foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
?>            <?php */ ?>

Comment: <div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
   $category->getChildren()
    </ul>
</div>              
<?php //endif ?>

Comment: It's look like custom module for navigation so i need to check that module in details. May be something going wrong in block........How can i check code??

Comment: Thanks. I think, the code is too long for release here in comment box. So you need to check navigation.php or airhotels.phtml? I have to think how to deploy.

Comment: Sure you will think and do let me know..

Comment: Can I send you ftp by mail? So could you provide me your e-mail adress?! Or do you have drop box or skype?

Comment: Please save my gmail and skype id "rkrameshraja"